# Is it possible to disable the image alignment options in the post editor?

Tags: tinymce, editor, visual-editor, wp-editor

By default, when you insert an image into a post, it has some image alignment options (see below).

[image: Alignment options in WordPress]

In my theme I want every image to be full width. Of course, it's easy for me to change the front-end display of the images. But--in terms of usability--I don't want to cause the user to think that they are able to change the alignment. Is it possible to disable those alignment options?

Answer (score 0):

You could always disable them through css.

E.g.:

```
.mce-i-dashicon.dashicons-align-left {
    display: none;
}
```